# Spring event publisher and multiple listeners

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In spring boot, I have one event publiser and there are multiple listeners, if one listener failed, it will impact other listener to consume the event?

Is there any configuration to avoid this case?
when one listener failed, the other listeners can still process the published event. Thanks.

Comment: First I'd like to mention that the basic Spring application listeners should't be used to implement a full-blown event driven architecture. That being said making the listeners `@ASync` will reduce the dependency between listeners. However this will also mean that if everything should need to commit in one transaction you will loose that ability...

Comment: Thank you Meinum, one more question, do you know that is there any way to disable one of the lisenters dynamicly? For example, I have 3 listeners, how can I disable one so that it will not consume the publish event? is there a switch to configure that? Thanks.

Comment: Not out-of-the-box there isn't (unless it is at startup time you could use the `@Conditional` rules from Spring Boot but those don't apply at runtime).

Comment: @M.Deinum any reason not to use Spring application listeners for event-driven apps?